# getting error ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE Position: 98

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to find `customer` of the `minimum` value i tried like this

```
select info->'customer'
from orders
where cast(info->'items'->>'qty' as INTEGER) =
      (select min(cast(info->'items'->>'qty' as INTEGER)))
```

here is my code

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/79606/17

getting error
**: aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE Position: 98**

**expected answer 
"Josh William"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subquery misses a `FROM` clause. Try:

```
select info->'customer'
from orders
where cast(info->'items'->>'qty' as INTEGER) =
      (select min(cast(info->'items'->>'qty' as INTEGER))
              from orders)
```